# Url rewrite for a domain name

Tags: php, html, apache, http

Ok so i have hosting with godaddy and i have 2 websites hosted with them. I make a htaccess rule and add it into my main dir and it effect both domain names. Im just wondering if there anything i can add to it to only work for the one domain name ??
My mod rewrite rule is has follwed

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)_ index.php?pageid=$1
```

When i add this to my main dir it effect both websites i have hosted.
The rule ment to be changing this
mysite.com?index.php 
to this
mysite.com/index_

But has i have said i need to some how set a domain name in side it some how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line before your `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomainname.com$
```

Your rule will affect only this domain, your .htaccess should look like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?pageid=$1
```

This would match

```
http://www.mysite.com/week1
```

and rewrite it to

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?pageid=week1
```

Then you can access `$_GET['pageid']` to get the value

Comment: then could i echo out $1 to get the page id ?? i try and echo out the get page id but get the full url...

Comment: i just want it so when a user goes to   mydomainname.com/week1 that it will show mydomainname.index?pageid=week1  and then i get the week1 some how.

Comment: Ok, then see my reedit :)